# Splitting up a list with all values sitting in the same index in Python

Tags: python, sql, list

Im pretty new to Python.
I have a list which looks like the following:

```
list = [('foo,bar,bash',)]
```

I grabbed it from and sql table (someone created the most rubbish sql table!), and I cant adjust it. This is literally the only format I can pull it in. I need to chop it up. I can't split it by index:

```
print list[0]
```

because that just literally gives me:

```
[('foo,bar,bash',)]
```

How can I split this up? I want to split it up and write it into another list.

Thank you.

Comment: `print list[0][0].split(",")` duplicate question, got a lot same question here..

Answer (score 1):

`list = [('foo,bar,bash',)]` is a list which contains a tuple with 1 element. You should also use a different variable name instead of `list` because `list` is a python built in.

You can split that one element using `split`:

```
lst = [('foo,bar,bash',)]
print lst[0][0].split(',')
```

Output:

`['foo', 'bar', 'bash']`

---

If the tuple contains more than one element, you can loop through it:

```
lst = [('foo,bar,bash','1,2,3')]
for i in lst[0]:
    print i.split(',')
```